# Pandas: Incorrect Result when multiplying two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am going through the Pandas-Kaggle information here:

**DataSet**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/16cwjq5ibtcmzgi/Lookup211.csv?dl=0

**Action I want to take**
I want to combine the two columns.

**Issue I am getting**

But for some reason, even simple multiplication is not yielding the correct value.

This is what i have

```
wine.points_normal = (pd.to_numeric(wine.points) * pd.to_numeric(wine.price))
```

As you can see `0.0 * 85` is not equating as 0

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

```
wine[['points', 'price']].head().to_dict()
```

yields

```
{'points': {0: 96, 1: 96, 2: 96, 3: 96, 4: 95},
 'price': {0: 235.0, 1: 110.0, 2: 90.0, 3: 65.0, 4: 66.0}}
```

Comment: could you post the output of `wine[['points', 'price']].head().to_dict()` in your question

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you need to multiply the columns of the Dataframe

Comment: You were to post the output of the code I gave above ie to share the data. In your question you provided an image which is not recommended.

Comment: Hi @ddejohn what are those things I could provide in this context? Id be happy to expand

Comment: Could you try the answer below

Comment: Hi @KU99 I am so sorry. What are you recommending I try?

Comment: for the given sample, can you reproduce your issue? if not, it's not a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataframe, that dataset is not available to download.

Comment: Using the dataset you provided, do you still get the error? I cannot reproduce your error

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't use dot syntax when assigning new columns. Should be `wine["points_normal"] = wine.points * wine.price`

Comment: Put the dataset in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/16cwjq5ibtcmzgi/Lookup211.csv?dl=0

Comment: I've loaded the data into a frame: There are no rows with `wine.price == 0`? `wine.at[90546, "price"]` does produce `4.0`?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your error, to mee seems fine. Seems like a cliche for IT but try to restar your kernel if you are in Jupyter notebook:
with "Restart & Clear Output" + "Restar & Run All"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and got 'RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars' when I ran the problematic entries by themselves. No warning, just wrong results like in your case when I multiplied the entire column. The numbers were not big, 56 times 4576. I 'fixed' the problem by setting the type to integer; df[column1].astype(int)*df[column2].

Comment: That is a totally different situation, unrelated to the question

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33254765)